Android log4j logging from compiled dependency not working
I am building a java class which will include various logging statements, and wish to compile this into a dependency which will be used by an Android application
(and separately in standalone java/desktop applications)
The class looks like this:
package com.example.shared;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class ExampleClass {

    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ExampleClass.class);
    
    public ExampleClass(){}
    
    public void printMessages(){
        logger.error("This is an error message from ExampleClass!");
        logger.warn("This is a warn message from ExampleClass!");
        logger.info("This is an info message from ExampleClass!");
        logger.debug("This is a debug message from ExampleClass!");
        logger.trace("This is a trace message from ExampleClass!");
    }
}

The dependency will be compiled with maven, with pom.xml as follows:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Shared</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

To use this in my android project, I have enabled local maven repositories and imported the artefact along with log4j api/core and an android runtime implementation:
app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
        resources.excludes.add("serviceAccountKey*.json")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'com.example:shared:1.0.0'

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.celeral:log4j2-android:1.0.0'
}

The log4j configuration I am trying to use (which should only print INFO lines) is provided in app/src/main/assets/log4j2.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

My android application main activity is setup as below:
package com.example.android;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import com.example.shared.ExampleClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainActivity.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Test logging from dependency
        ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
        ec.printMessages();
    }
}

However, when I attempt to run my application and test the logging statements, the configuration is ignored and all logging levels are printed:
E/ExampleClass: This is an error message from ExampleClass!
W/ExampleClass: This is a warn message from ExampleClass!
I/ExampleClass: This is an info message from ExampleClass!
D/ExampleClass: This is a debug message from ExampleClass!
V/ExampleClass: This is a trace message from ExampleClass!

But if I remove runtimeOnly 'com.celeral:log4j2-android:1.0.0' from app/build.gradle, I am met with the error below:
W/System.err: ERROR StatusLogger Unable to load services for service class org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider
W/System.err:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.callServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:110)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil$ServiceLoaderSpliterator.<init>(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:146)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadClassloaderServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:101)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:83)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:77)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.<init>(ProviderUtil.java:67)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:145)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:129)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:90)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:598)
W/System.err:     at com.example.android.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:14)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
W/System.err:     at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Although I do get the error line printed:
W/System.err: ERROR ExampleClass This is an error message from ExampleClass!

Why does this not work as required?
Update 1: Someone has voted to close this as "Needs more focus". There is only one problem requiring an answer - I have amended the last statement to reflect this,
Final edit:
After the update to log4j v2.24.1 (and the removal of celeral log4j2-android runtime dependency) it is clearer now what has been happening.
Log4j has been unable to find/resolve the configuration provided in the assets directory, and thus no loggers are defined. By default, the loggers I attempt to use are set to Level.ERROR, hence why the single error line:
W/System.err: ERROR ExampleClass This is an error message from ExampleClass!

was still being logged. The previous log4j-android, when in use, would simply forward everything to android Log class, which logs all levels in the console (not what I wanted).
The issue I am left trying to resolve is why the configuration won't load

TL;DR Upgrade to version 2.24.0 of the Log4j API.
Log4j API struggles to maintain compatibility with a lot of runtimes:

JRE versions from 8 to the latest,
GraalVM (does not support some JDK 8 methods and has other restrictions),
Android (does not support some JDK 8 methods),
SecurityManager (requires the usage of additional JDK 8 methods),
OSGi,
JPMS (has a caller sensitivity and requires some care to call methods from the context of the right module).

The cause of your failure is the lack of a standard JDK 8 method in Android. The method call was introduces to fix a problem with our SecurityManager and JPMS support around version 2.18.0.
It was removed in version 2.24.0, which should solve your problem.

Ok, so my build.gradle now contains:
`implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.24.0'

runtimeOnly 'com.celeral:log4j2-android:1.0.0' and I have `rootLogger.level = INFO` 

set in assets/log4j2.properties, but I'm still getting DEBUG lines printed

The com.celeral:log4j2-android artifact is an alternative implementation of the Log4j API, which forwards everything to the Android Log class. Since you are not using Log4j Core, modifying its configuration file will not change anything.

I've removed com.celeral.log4j2-android:1.0.0, only the org.apache.logging dependencies (api and core) remain. new error: I/com.example: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~MLF2ZshZzBIhJrgJjHw41g==/com.example-3Fbkjvp4obnGh8xK-dY_6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~MLF2ZshZzBIhJrgJjHw41g==/com.example-3Fbkjvp4obnGh8xK-dY_6A==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~MLF2ZshZzBIhJrgJjHw41g==/com.example-3Fbkjvp4obnGh8xK-dY_6A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]

That is happening with version 2.24.1? Can you report the issue?

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/3056
